# The Mean Value Theorem with distance/rate/time

Tags: calculus

How do you use the MVT to solve a problem like this?
"At 2:00pm a car's speedometer reads $20mph$, and at 2:10pm it reads $35mph$. Use the Mean Value Theorem to find an acceleration the car  must  achieve." 
I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- Assume that acceleration is continuous and the car is moving in a straight line
- Calculate the average acceleration over the ten minutes
- Consider what would happen to the car's speed at $2$:$10$pm if its acceleration was consistently higher than this average and it was travelling at $20$mph at $2$pm
- Consider what would happen to the car's speed at $2$:$10$pm if its acceleration was consistently lower  than this average and it was travelling at $20$mph at $2$pm
- Answer the question

Comment: how do I calculate the avg. acceleration? I have no idea.

Comment: One possibility might be total change in velocity divided by total change in time, in the same way that average velocity is total change in position divided by total change in time.